# Yii 2 path to frontend and backend

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I need to add/register a css file but I cant get the path to the `frontend`;

What's the Yii `Yii::app()->baseUrl` equivalent in Yii 2 ?

I tryed:

`Yii::$app->basePath` and it gives me : `c:/wamp/www/project/frontend`

I only need `/project/frontend`

Comment: Why do you need only `/project/frontend`? Is it a relative path to your webroot?

Comment: i was looking in the source code of yii2, and thats the format of the urls; i want to keep that format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii::app()->baseUrl equivalent in Yii 2  is

```
  \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   $baseUrl = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);
   $scriptUrl = Yii::app()->request->scriptUrl;
   $themeUrl = Yii::app()->theme->getBaseUrl();
```